# Nested loop for sequential recoding

Tags: r, loops, stata

I'm doing a sequence analysis on a large data sample. What I want to do is to rewrite my old Stata code in R, so that all of my analysis is performed in one single environment.

However, I would also like to improve it a little bit - the code is pretty long, and I would like to rewrite it using loops, so that it becomes more readable. Unfortunately my loop-writing skills are questionable.

1st loop [I think it needs to include an `if` statement]

I would like to write a loop for the following commands:

```
dt$dur.ofA1 <-(dt$M2_3R_A_1 - dt$M2_2R_A_1)
dt$dur.ofB1<-(dt$M2_3R_B_1 - dt$M2_2R_B_1)
dt$dur.ofC1<-(dt$M2_3R_C_1 - dt$M2_2R_C_1)
dt$dur.ofD1<-(dt$M2_3R_D_1 - dt$M2_2R_D_1)
dt$dur.ofE1<-(dt$M2_3R_E_1 - dt$M2_2R_E_1)
dt$dur.ofF1<-(dt$M2_3R_F_1 - dt$M2_2R_F_1)
dt$dur.ofG1<-(dt$M2_3R_G_1 - dt$M2_2R_G_1)
dt$dur.ofH1<-(dt$M2_3R_H_1 - dt$M2_2R_H_1)
dt$dur.ofA2<-(dt$M2_3R_A_2 - dt$M2_2R_A_2)
dt$dur.ofB2<-(dt$M2_3R_B_2 - dt$M2_2R_B_2)
dt$dur.ofC2<-(dt$M2_3R_C_2 - dt$M2_2R_C_2)
dt$dur.ofD2<-(dt$M2_3R_D_2 - dt$M2_2R_D_2)
dt$dur.ofE2<-(dt$M2_3R_E_2 - dt$M2_2R_E_2)
dt$dur.ofF2<-(dt$M2_3R_F_2 - dt$M2_2R_F_2)
dt$dur.ofG2<-(dt$M2_3R_G_2 - dt$M2_2R_G_2)
dt$dur.ofH2<-(dt$M2_3R_H_2 - dt$M2_2R_H_2)
dt$dur.ofA3<-(dt$M2_3R_A_3 - dt$M2_2R_A_3)
dt$dur.ofB3<-(dt$M2_3R_B_3 - dt$M2_2R_B_3)
dt$dur.ofC3<-(dt$M2_3R_C_3 - dt$M2_2R_C_3)
dt$dur.ofD3<-(dt$M2_3R_D_3 - dt$M2_2R_D_3)
dt$dur.ofE3<-(dt$M2_3R_E_3 - dt$M2_2R_E_3)
dt$dur.ofF3<-(dt$M2_3R_F_3 - dt$M2_2R_F_3)
dt$dur.ofG3<-(dt$M2_3R_G_3 - dt$M2_2R_G_3)
dt$dur.ofH3<-(dt$M2_3R_H_3 - dt$M2_2R_H_3)
```

My attempt:

```
db1 <- paste(rep("M2_", 24), "2R_", rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 8)],3), "_",
            rep(seq(from=1, to =3), 8),
            sep = "")
db2 <- paste(rep("M2_", 24), "3R_", rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 8)],3), "_",
             rep(seq(from=1, to =3), 8),
             sep = "")
dur <- paste(rep("dur.of", 24), rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 8)],3),
             rep(seq(from=1, to =3), 8),
             sep = "")

dur <- as.list(dur)

for(e in dur){
  for (j in db1){
    for (i in db2){
  {
  dt[,e] <- dt[,i] - dt[,j]
}
```

I think the loop needs an `if` statement in the middle, so that it stops at a single item (subtracts `A1` from `A1`, `A2` from `A2` etc.) from the list.

2) The second case is a little bit more complicated, but essentially it is the same case as described above:

The `M2_2R_A_1` (start) `M2_3R_A_1` (finish) indicate the yearly dates in which an educational activity took place. I would like to generate 1948:2013 variables that indicate that an activity took place in a particular year (`stedu==x`). A part of my Stata code is as follows (it goes on like that up to 2013):

```
recode stedu1948(0=2) if M2_2R_A_1<=1948 & 1948<= M2_3R_A_1 | M2_2R_A_2<=1948 & 1948<= M2_3R_A_2 | M2_2R_A_3<=1948 & 1948<= M2_3R_A_3
recode stedu1949(0=2) if M2_2R_A_1<=1949 & 1949<= M2_3R_A_1 | M2_2R_A_2<=1949 & 1949<= M2_3R_A_2 | M2_2R_A_3<=1949 & 1949<= M2_3R_A_3
recode stedu1950(0=2) if M2_2R_A_1<=1950 & 1950<= M2_3R_A_1 | M2_2R_A_2<=1950 & 1950<= M2_3R_A_2 | M2_2R_A_3<=1950 & 1950<= M2_3R_A_3
```

So in order to write a loop I would also need to include some conditions in order to stop the loop at a given point.

Comment: Isn't this just `dt[dur] <- dt[db2] - dt[db1]` ? For loops are rarely needed for this sort of operation.

Comment: Thank you :) the operation gives a list, but it works well for the 1st loop

Answer (score 0):

For your first item, use @thelatemail's suggestion. For second item, consider the following `for` loop using the `ifelse()` function:

```
for (i in 1948:2013) {
    dt[[paste0("stedu", i)]] <- ifelse((dt$M2_2R_A_1 <= i & dt$M2_3R_A_1 >= i) OR  
                                       (dt$M2_2R_A_2 <= i & dt$M2_3R_A_2 >= i) OR
                                       (dt$M2_2R_A_3 <= i & dt$M2_3R_A_3 >= i),                 
                                       2,                               
                                       dt[[paste0("stedu", i)]]  
}
```